# Search for a specific value of an object in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

I need to look up all images within several pages of my InDesign CC2018 document which containers have a negative (-100%) value of the y-scale AND a specific negative value (-40%) of the image itself.

I looked up InDesigns Search object dialogue, but I don't see these options. Is there any chance I can do a change like

```
find all images(container -100% AND object-40%) changeto (container 100% AND object 40% )
```

as a bulk-action - how?

The containers do have a object style but that one doesn't set these values as they are set manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this script:
Please note it's a very basic attempt and that you may need more features (like checking if an object is locked, or on a locked layer, which would throw an error)

```
(function() {
 if (app.documents.length == 0) {
     return
 }

 var
     doc = app.documents[0],
     graphics = doc.allGraphics;

 for (i = 0; graphics.length > i; i++) {
     if (graphics[i].parent.absoluteFlip == Flip.VERTICAL &&
         graphics[i].parent.absoluteVerticalScale == -100 &&
         graphics[i].absoluteFlip == Flip.NONE &&
         graphics[i].absoluteVerticalScale == 40
     ) {
         app.activeWindow.transformReferencePoint = AnchorPoint.CENTER_ANCHOR;
         graphics[i].parent.absoluteFlip = Flip.NONE;
     }
 }
})
();
```